# I need help , Object does not contain a definition for 'Checked'

Tags: c#

Hey i am trying to do homework. I was watching and typing code when the professionel type its worked but mine didnt work.

> Full Error : CS1061   'object' does not contain a definition for
>   'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

```
if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    if (kayitokuma["kullaniciadi"].ToString() == textBox1.Text && 
        kayitokuma["parola"].ToString() == textBox2.Text && 
        kayitokuma["yetki"].ToString() == "Kullanıcı");
    {
```

Comment: It looks like `radioButton2` is of type `object`, how is it defined?

Comment: press F12 on radioButton2 to go to definition

Comment: private object radioButton2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `radioButton2` is of type `object`, which don't have any `Checked` property.

So, your `radioButton2` needs to be of type [`RadioButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netframework-4.7.2) and then you can use [`RadioButton.Checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

Instanciate your radio button as `private RadioButton radioButton2`.

Comment: Can you type how can i change this line exactly ?

Comment: Change `private object radioButton2;` with `private RadioButton radioButton2;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked !!

Comment: why people - me i dont understand. There is a student, trying to know. They are GOD and just click "-". Stackoverflow everytime same.